# Scala server needs to manage many clients

Tags: scala, client-server, remote-actors

We need to create a Server with Scala RemotActors, that can handle multiple clients. Eg a chat server that replies every received message back to all connected clients. Our current attempt is to create one actor per client that can listen and reply to all received messages. But the the dynamic registration of the actors does not work.

```
import actors.{Actor, OutputChannel}
import actors.remote.{RemoteActor, Node, FreshNameCreator}

object Server extends Actor{

    class ConnectedClient(id:Symbol,out:OutputChannel[Any]) extends Actor{
        start

        def act {
            loop {
                react {
                    case m:ServerMessage =>
                        out ! m
                    case m:ClientMessage =>
                        Server ! m
                }
            }
        }
    }

    RemoteActor.alive(9999)
    RemoteActor.register('server, this ) //'
    println("Server started.")

    var clients = new collection.mutable.HashSet[ConnectedClient]

    def act  {
        loop {
            react {
                case 'connect => //'
                    println("Server: New Client")
                    val id = FreshNameCreator.newName
                    val client = new ConnectedClient(id,sender)
                    clients += client
                    RemoteActor.register(id, client) // This seems not to work
                    reply(id)
                case ClientMessage(m) =>
                    println("Server: received: " + m)
                    for( client <- clients )
                        client ! ServerMessage(m)
                case m =>
                    println("Server: Unknown Message: " + m)
            }
        }
    }
}

case class ServerMessage(m:String)
case class ClientMessage(m:String)

class Client(serverNode:Node) extends Actor{

    println("Client: connecting...")
    val server = RemoteActor.select( serverNode, 'server ) //'

    start

    def act{

        //we want the symbol that is intended to identify our personal Actor at the Server
        val id = (server !? 'connect).asInstanceOf[Symbol] //'
        val personalServer = RemoteActor.select( serverNode, id)

        println("Client["+id+"]: connected")

        loop{
            react{
                case ServerMessage(m) => 
                    println("Client["+id+"]: " + m)
                case m:String =>
                    personalServer ! ClientMessage(m)
                case m =>
                    println("Server: Unknown Message: " + m)
            }
        }
    }
}

object Main{
    def main(args:Array[String]){

        Server.start

        val serverNode = Node("localhost",9999)
        val clientA = new Client(serverNode)
        val clientB = new Client(serverNode)
        val clientC = new Client(serverNode)

        clientA ! "Hello. I am A."
        clientB ! "Hello. I am B."
        clientC ! "Hello. I am C."
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `alive` and `register` inside the `act` method.

Comment: yes I already found that out myself, any Idea why I have to do that?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but since each thread acts as an actor, calling them from the Main thread registers the Main-actor to the outside, not the one you want. Would have to try though.